# How to create a link that inserts a string in to a query of a html page?

Tags: php, html, string

My intention is to make `$suggestion[$ss_count]` become a hyperlink that leads you to index2.php and inserts the `$suggestion[$ss_count]` in to the query field. Since my query is sent by post how can I do this?

PHP:

```
if ($_POST['query'])

{
    $query = urlencode($_POST['query']);
    $s_count = 0;
    $ss_count = 0;
    $query = 'http://www.dictionaryapi.com/api/v1/references/collegiate/xml/'.$query.'?';     
    $xml = new SimpleXMLIterator(file_get_contents($query));
    foreach ($xml -> suggestion as $suggestion[$s_count])
    {
        $s_count++;
    }
if ($s_count > 1)
{
    echo ('<h2>Spelling suggestions</h2>');
    while ($ss_count <=$s_count)
    {
    echo ($suggestion[$ss_count].'<br>');
    $ss_count++;
    }

 }
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Search Attempt</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action='safegoogle.php'>
    <label for="query">Query</label><br/>
    <input name="query" type="text" size="60" maxlength="60" value="" /><br /><br /> 
    <select name ="agg">
        <option value="Aggregated">Aggregated</option>
        <option value="Non-Aggregated">Non-Aggregated</option>
        <option value="Bing">Bing</option>
        <option value="Blekko">Blekko</option>
        <option value="Faroo">Faroo</option>
    </select>
    <input name="bt_search" type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
<h2> Results </h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it will be easier if you just put the php code and the html into one file and make your form post to it self...that way your php variables will be accessible from anywhere within the file....and you can now intelligently mix code and markup to achieve what you want.